# Get list of select items from database and populate objects

Tags: entity-framework

I am trying to Populate an object inside another object while avoiding two things:

1. Getting all the items in table
2. Making a separate call to the db for each item

Here is my code

Classes

```
public class Profile: BaseEntity
{
    public Picture Picture { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public partial class Picture : BaseEntity
{
   public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

Services

```
public class ProfileService : IProfileService
{
    private readonly IRepository<Profile> _profileRepo;
    private readonly IRepository<Picture> _pictureRepo;


     public ProfileService(IRepository<Profile> profileRepo, IRepository<Picture> pictureRepo)
     {
         _profileRepo = profileRepo;
         _pictureRepo = pictureRepo;
     }

     public IEnumerable<Profile> GetProfiles()
     {
          IEnumerable<Profile> profiles = _profileRepo.Table.ToList();
          // I am guessing I would retrieve pictures here based off of picture 
          // ids that are in the profiles   
          // than I would populate the profiles with the pictures
     }
}
```

Also in the database PictureId is a foreign key in Profile table.

Comment: so you want to get a IEnumerable of Profiles, including their picture?

Comment: yes, that is what i want

Answer (score 0):

If there is a relation between the objects then you should be able to just create a method in your repository to do:

```
public IEnumerable<Profile> GetAllProfilesWithPictures()
{
    return your_context.Profiles.Include(x => x.Picture);
}
```

This will return all the profiles, along with their picture.

Not quite sure on what you mean when you say `Getting all items in table`..  If you want to limit what you get then you can put a where clause or whatever on the above statement.